# Magento 2: The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "product-details" component

Tags: magento2, error, admin-panel

I am getting the following error when I try to edit a product in Magento Admin. What should I do solve this issue?

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The
>   configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for
>   "product-details" component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that somehow the attribute group **Product Details** is gone. You need to create that **Attribute Group** with the following attributes.

- status
- name
- sku
- sku_type
- price
- price_type
- tax_class_id
- quantity_and_stock_status
- weight
- weight_type
- visibility
- category_ids
- news_from_date
- news_to_date
- country_of_manufacture

Comment: Already listed all above attributes in General group. Still not working! I am not able to create a group with "Product Details".. Could you please help?

Comment: Did you ever get this issue resolved? I am having the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. So we need to create the "Product Details" attribute group in the attribute set. It should contain at least one attribute. Do not leave it empty.